# With iptables, is there a way for accept only one specific ip for all protocol and all ports ?

Tags: security, iptables

The question is in the title :) 
Concretely, I want configure a new remote server. I like take my time and security :p so , I want allow access only for my local ip during installation and configuration of my remote server

If there is a beter solution than iptables, I'm interested of course !

Comment: I believe your question is getting down-voted because the answer is so trivial even a cursory search of good or the man pages for iptables should provide an answer.

Comment: I understand, but I didn't know every protocol (ssh, http, ...) or ways to access to my remote server. This is the reason I'm looking for a rule or a list of rules who deny access for all protocols except me

Comment: Right, but the first hit in a google search for "iptables block all but one ip" gives you the right answer (a unix.stackexchange article: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11851/iptables-allow-certain-ips-and-block-all-other-connection).

Comment: I highly recommend checking out the excellent "How do I ask a good question?" page: http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask
It is relevant not just here, but anywhere you are asking questions (both the real world AND the internets!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can use iptables to do this. Remember that iptables rules are evaluated in order and first match wins.  Put a rule at the beginning of your INPUT chain allowing the source IP address that is your local machine, follow it with a rule that drops everything else.